# Store password ciphers using Powershell ? DPAPI/AES

Tags: aes, storage

I am making a script that requires to have a lot of server's IP and their passwords stored in a file.

I wanted to use Windows DPAPI, but as we can easily retrieve the plain text version it is not very good.

I then tried to use AES.
Now my question is: how, using AES, could I store the keys (1 for each IP's ?) so it is possible for the script to decrypt passwords, but difficult for someone un-authorized to read the file containing the passwords?

Answer (score 3):

DPAPI stores protected data encrypted with the user's DPAPI key, which is in turn encrypted with a derivative (via PBKDF2) of the NTLM password. Furthermore, the DPAPI-related key information is stored in a protected memory region within the security subsystem (LSA), making it particularly difficult to compromise the master keys outside of an administrative context.

The two primary concerns in the threat model of DPAPI are offline attacks (e.g. stolen hard-disk) or a malicious user trying to compromise the DPAPI-protected data of another user. Both of these threats are suitably protected against with DPAPI.

Your concern that DPAPI allows for easy recovery of the data is unfounded; the fact that you can recover the information is due to you being logged in as the legitimate user. Logging in as any other user would make this impossible, as would trying to recover the DPAPI-protected data from an offline disk image (unless you know the password of the user who saved the data).

Any solution you implement on your own with AES (or any other cipher) will be less secure in these regards.

That said, if your application's security model involves giving service passwords to your users in an encrypted text file, there's very little to stop them decrypting it and getting at the passwords. This sounds like a candidate for having *them* authenticate to the backend systems with their own individual user accounts, or having an intermediary service which the users authenticate to which can then make back-end service requests on their behalf.

Comment: Thx for replying
So using Sys.SecureString wont allow anyone else get those data.
Thing is, as I have to store passwords on a file, I can't store them as SecureString (it will turn to SecureString as String in the file), making it impossible to use as passwords.

Comment: So i'm currently working on using both DPAPI and AES(for storage), but that just displaces the problem : where and how to store the key ?

Comment: @Svart You shouldn't need to store a key, or use AES. `CryptProtectData` encrypts your data and that's that.

Comment: Actually the script is designed to be used on one specific machine and executes requests on remote servers
I would like to make it hard to read the passwords file in case someone malicious gets it, but still usable for the sys admin

Comment: @Svart You didn't make this clear at all in your question. In which case, have the script take a master password, produce 384 bits (48 bytes) with it using PBKDF2 (e.g. .NET's Rfc2898DeriveBytes class), then split that into three 128-bit values for encryption key, IV, and authenticity key. Use the first two to encrypt the message with AES-128, and use the last one as a key for a HMAC-SHA256 signature on the encrypted data. That way the administrator only needs to enter a master password to launch the script, and an attacker can't decrypt or change the encrypted data.

Comment: Thanks for replies
So as I understrand it would consist in crypt passwords with symetric key,
and this key with an asymetric one ? 
So the administrator just would have to enter a passphrase to unlock AES key ?

Comment: I finnaly left the choice between using DPAPI or AES but I think each is not perfect : 
DPAPI : makes impossible to extract passwords from the file from anywhere else than the admin system, but easily if one somehow gains access to the the sys
AES : makes possible to extract password from anywhere if one gets both key file and passwords file
In each case, fraudulent access give the ability to extract passwords, wich I'd like to prevent

Comment: Some things I dont understand :
 1--- What's the difference between using 128-bytes key+128-bytes IV and 256-bytes key ? 
  These are both random. Does the IV changes randomly at each password, if yes how to retrieve it
  to decrypt ?
 2--- What would be the use of SHA256 signature on crypted data ? I dont get the last sentence of your message. What would the master password ?

 
 3--- What if I used standart AES key as a master password for the admin to use ? I think it would work, but how secure would it be ?
Thanks for further explanations

Comment: I got a precision from the administrator : script will be used as a Schedule Task, so it is impossible
to prompt admin for a password/key. So as at the end, I need a way to crypt passwords without prompting a passphrase. 
I have to make passwords retrieval the most difficult possible for a prospective malicious person who would somehow 
have gained access to main server.... With such params I don't know how I could do it.